# How to get a row from a Table with no ids

Tags: sql

I have two tables, table A and table B, table A has and Id,a,b and c rows , Table B just has a,b and c and what i want (but i dont know how to do it) is to get a single row from Table B
(i would be something like comparinga,b,and c at the same time)

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT A.id, B.a, B.b, B.c
  FROM A
  JOIN B
    ON(A.a=B.a)
    AND(A.b=B.b)
    AND(A.c=B.c)
```

But I'd change your database structure and add foreign keyto table B referencing table A. It would really help you with this and later cases.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest changing your table structure.

```
TableA ( id primary key)

TableB(colA,colB,colC,fid foreign key refrencing TableA.id )
```

So now you dont have to store colA,colB,colC values in both TableA and TableB

```
Select B.*
From TableA A
Join TableB B
On A.id=B.fid
```